# How to reset scheduled (@Scheduled) in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have spring boot application, where I need to refresh every 20 seconds so I created this:

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/20 * * * * *")
@GetMapping("/refresh")
public void refresh(){
    letterServiceI.refreshQueue();
}
```

And it works perfectly, but when I am adding row to database and before it was empty I want to reset timer to 20 seconds again, is there a way to do it?

```
@Override
public Letter add(String name, String content, String pin) {

    if (letterRepositoryI.checkIfNotEmpty().isEmpty()){
        //if empty -> reset scheduler to 20 again
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just call the method annotated with `@Scheduled(cron="*/20 * * * * *")` whenever you add a new row to the database.

If you wanted to make your Scheduled expression more concise, you could as well use `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

I acknowledge that this might lead to the scheduled reset taking place shortly after the manual call, but I could not find a way to reset this timer manually in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled).

Comment: But this method is called every 20 seconds and when its called for example at 19:40:20 and then I am adding a new row at 19:40:30 and refreshing it still will execute at 19:40:40 but I want it to refresh 20 seconds after I added new row so at 19:40:50

Comment: @sadge_user I updated my answer, I could not find a way to make this work. Would it be so problematic if the refresh took place only ten seconds later in this scenario? Afterwards, it will be back to the 20s interval again

Comment: It is just something that you can add to the response to make it more relevant. InitialDelay to define how much seconds should it wait to start for the first time

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem, but without finding solution.
I got around this by creating a timer with a smaller interval and maintaining a last run date for the job.

Globally creates a last run date (For example using a singleton pattern).

```
private long lastScreenUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

When you want to reset the timer, simply change the value of the last run

```
lastScreenUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Your scheduler will need to do something like this

```
public static final int DELAY_RELOAD_TIMEOUT = 20000;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void syncJob() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - AppInfo.getIstance().getLastScreenUpdate() > DELAY_RELOAD_TIMEOUT) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //DO THE STUFF HERE!
            AppInfo.getIstance().setLastScreenUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        });
    }
}
```